# install a external jar to local repository according to maven's official tutorial,but failed

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

the command I used(according to maven's official tutorial:[maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)):

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=algs4-1.0.4.jar -DgroupID=edu.princeton.cs -DartifactID=algs4 -Dversion=1.0.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

---

the error info told `groupID` and `artifactID` are missing,so I try to modify the command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=algs4-1.0.4.jar -groupID=edu.princeton.cs -artifactID=algs4 -Dversion=1.0.4 -Dpackaging=jar
```

you know,that's even worse.

I also try some solution from some answers here,they don't work either.

---

- expected result is,you know,install the jar.
- actual results is:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------< org.apache.maven:standalone-pom >-------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.460 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-09T00:23:39+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR]   [0]  'groupId' is missing.
[ERROR]   [1]  'artifactId' is missing.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled `groupId` and `artifactId` as `groupID` and `artifactID`.

Comment: Ok!jusus!I don't know what to say to myself.Stupid me.and thanks for answering this question